# STL Sort - Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, stl

Program in `C++`. I sorted a vector using STL sort and the boolean comparator (here, `cmp1` and `cmp2` functions). However, upon running the program and reading the values of the vector, it returns:
`Debug Assertion Failed!, Line:1618, Expression: invalid comparator`. Here, the function that returns the error from the algorithm library is:

```
// FUNCTION TEMPLATE _Debug_lt_pred
template <class _Pr, class _Ty1, class _Ty2,
    enable_if_t<is_same_v<_Remove_cvref_t<_Ty1>, _Remove_cvref_t<_Ty2>>, int> = 0>
constexpr bool _Debug_lt_pred(_Pr&& _Pred, _Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right) noexcept(
    noexcept(_Pred(_Left, _Right)) && noexcept(_Pred(_Right, _Left))) {
    // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering, when the arguments are the cv-same-type
    const auto _Result = static_cast<bool>(_Pred(_Left, _Right));
    if (_Result) {
        _STL_VERIFY(!_Pred(_Right, _Left), "invalid comparator");
    }

    return _Result;
}

template <class _Pr, class _Ty1, class _Ty2,
    enable_if_t<!is_same_v<_Remove_cvref_t<_Ty1>, _Remove_cvref_t<_Ty2>>, int> = 0>
constexpr bool _Debug_lt_pred(_Pr&& _Pred, _Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right) noexcept(noexcept(_Pred(_Left, _Right))) {
    // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right); no debug checks as the types differ
    return static_cast<bool>(_Pred(_Left, _Right));
}
```

This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#define DIM 10006
using namespace std;

bool cmp1(int st, int dr) {
    return (st >= dr);
}

bool cmp2(int st, int dr) {
    return (st <= dr);
}

void Scan(int& n, int& m, char& c, int v[])
{
    cin >> n >> m >> c;
    for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++)
        cin >> v[i];
}

void Print(int n, int m, int v[])
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << v[k] << ' ';
            k++;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int v[DIM];
    int n, m;
    char c;
    Scan(n, m, c, v);
    if (c == '+')
        sort(v, v + n * m, cmp1);
    else //c == '-'
        sort(v, v + n * m, cmp2);
    Print(n, m, v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The operators `<=` and `>=` don't defined a strict weak order as `cmp(a, a)` is `true`.

Comment: The rules for a [strict weak order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) are: irreflexive: `cmp(a, a) == false`, asymmetry: `cmp(a, b) == true` implies `cmp(b, a) == false`, transitive: `cmp(a, b) == true && cmp(b,c) == true` implies `cmp(a, c) == true`, transitivity of incomparable: `cmp(a, b) == false && cmp(b, a) == false && cmp(b, c) == false && cmp(c, b) == false` implies `cmp(a, c) == false && cmp(c, a) == false`. The comparator of `std::sort()` has to define a strict weak ordering on the sequence of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparators must return false for equal elements. Change

```
bool cmp1(int st, int dr) {
    return (st >= dr);
}

bool cmp2(int st, int dr) {
    return (st <= dr);
}
```

to

```
bool cmp1(int st, int dr) {
    return (st > dr);
}

bool cmp2(int st, int dr) {
    return (st < dr);
}
```

A comparator should only return true when the first argument must be placed before the second argument in the sort. If they return true for equal arguments then *some* algorithms are going to get into a loop endlessly swapping equal elements.

Second time I've seen this question today.